# Problems in product page opencart

Tags: php, ajax

I have a part of code:

```
<?php
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/product');

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $path = '';

            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

            $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

            foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
                if (!$path) {
                    $path = $path_id;
                } else {
                    $path .= '_' . $path_id;
                }

                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

                if ($category_info) {
                    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                        'text' => $category_info['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path)
                    );
                }
            }

            // Set the last category breadcrumb
            $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

            if ($category_info) {
                $url = '';

                if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                    $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
                }

                if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                    $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
                }

                if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                    $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
                }

                if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                    $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
                }

                $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text' => $category_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url)
                );
            }
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');

        if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_brand'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer')
            );

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $manufacturer_info = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($this->request->get['manufacturer_id']);

            if ($manufacturer_info) {
                $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text' => $manufacturer_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] . $url)
                );
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search']) || isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_search'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', $url)
            );
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
        } else {
            $product_id = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

        if ($product_info) {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                $url .= '&manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $product_info['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'])
            );

            $this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title']);
            $this->document->setDescription($product_info['meta_description']);
            $this->document->setKeywords($product_info['meta_keyword']);
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id']), 'canonical');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js');
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/magnific-popup.css');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');

            $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];

            $data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
            $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
            $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
            $data['text_reward'] = $this->language->get('text_reward');
            $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
            $data['text_stock'] = $this->language->get('text_stock');
            $data['text_discount'] = $this->language->get('text_discount');
            $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
            $data['text_option'] = $this->language->get('text_option');
            $data['text_minimum'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_minimum'), $product_info['minimum']);
            $data['text_write'] = $this->language->get('text_write');
            $data['text_login'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_login'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL'));
            $data['text_note'] = $this->language->get('text_note');
            $data['text_tags'] = $this->language->get('text_tags');
            $data['text_related'] = $this->language->get('text_related');
            $data['text_payment_recurring'] = $this->language->get('text_payment_recurring');
            $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');
$this->load->language('checkout/checkout');

            $data['text_address_existing'] = $this->language->get('text_address_existing');
            $data['text_address_new'] = $this->language->get('text_address_new');
            $data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
            $data['text_none'] = $this->language->get('text_none');
            $data['text_title'] = $this->language->get('text_title');
            $data['text_titulofrete'] = $this->language->get('text_titulofrete');
            $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');
            $data['text_shipping_method'] = $this->language->get('text_shipping_method');
            $data['entry_postcode'] = $this->language->get('entry_postcode');
            $data['button_shipping'] = $this->language->get('button_shipping');
            $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

            $this->load->model('account/address');

            $data['addresses'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddresses();

            if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['postcode'])) {
                $data['postcode'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['postcode'];
            } else {
                $data['postcode'] = '';
            }

            $this->load->model('setting/setting');
            $data['freteproduto'] = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('freteproduto', $store_id = 0);

            $this->load->model('localisation/country');

            $data['countries'] = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountries();

            if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_method'])) {
                $data['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_method']['code'];
            } else {
                $data['shipping_method'] = '';
            }           $data['entry_qty'] = $this->language->get('entry_qty');
            $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
            $data['entry_review'] = $this->language->get('entry_review');
            $data['entry_rating'] = $this->language->get('entry_rating');
            $data['entry_good'] = $this->language->get('entry_good');
            $data['entry_bad'] = $this->language->get('entry_bad');

            $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
            $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
            $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
            $data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');
            $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
            $data['button_question'] = $this->language->get('button_question');

            $this->load->model('catalog/review');

            $data['tab_description'] = $this->language->get('tab_description');
            $data['tab_attribute'] = $this->language->get('tab_attribute');
            $data['tab_review'] = sprintf($this->language->get('tab_review'), $product_info['reviews']);

            $data['product_id'] = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
            $data['manufacturer'] = $product_info['manufacturer'];
            $data['manufacturers'] = $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $product_info['manufacturer_id']);
            $data['model'] = $product_info['model'];
            $data['reward'] = $product_info['reward'];
            $data['points'] = $product_info['points'];
            $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
                $data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
            } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
                $data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
            } else {
                $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
            }

            $this->load->model('tool/image');

            if ($product_info['image']) {
                $data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
            } else {
                $data['popup'] = '';
            }

            if ($product_info['image']) {
                $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height'));
            } else {
                $data['thumb'] = '';
            }

            $data['images'] = array();

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->get['product_id']);

            foreach ($results as $result) {

                $data['images'][] = array(
                    'popup' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')),
                    'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_additional_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_additional_height'))
                );
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $data['price'] = false;
            }

            if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
                $data['special'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $data['special'] = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $data['tax'] = $this->currency->format((float)$product_info['special'] ? $product_info['special'] : $product_info['price']);
            } else {
                $data['tax'] = false;
            }

            $discounts = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($this->request->get['product_id']);

            $data['discounts'] = array();

            foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
                $data['discounts'][] = array(
                    'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
                    'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')))
                );
            }

            $data['options'] = array();

            foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) {
                $product_option_value_data = array();

                foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
                    if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                        if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false));
                        } else {
                            $price = false;
                        }

                        $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                            'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                            'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                            'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                            'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                            'price'                   => $price,
                            'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                        );
                    }
                }

                $data['options'][] = array(
                    'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                    'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                    'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                    'name'                 => $option['name'],
                    'type'                 => $option['type'],
                    'value'                => $option['value'],
                    'required'             => $option['required']
                );
            }

            if ($product_info['minimum']) {
                $data['minimum'] = $product_info['minimum'];
            } else {
                $data['minimum'] = 1;
            }

            $data['review_status'] = $this->config->get('config_review_status');

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_guest') || $this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $data['review_guest'] = true;
            } else {
                $data['review_guest'] = false;
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $data['customer_name'] = $this->customer->getFirstName() . '&nbsp;' . $this->customer->getLastName();
            } else {
                $data['customer_name'] = '';
            }


            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/ask_question.css');
            $data['ask_status']  = $this->config->get('ask_question_status');   
            $data['ask_question'] = $this->url->link('product/ask_question', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']);

            $data['reviews'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$product_info['reviews']);
            $data['rating'] = (int)$product_info['rating'];

            // Captcha
            if ($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('review', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
                $data['captcha'] = $this->load->controller('captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha'));
            } else {
                $data['captcha'] = '';
            }

            $data['attribute_groups'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($this->request->get['product_id']);

            $data['products'] = array();

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductRelated($this->request->get['product_id']);

            foreach ($results as $result) {

                if ($result['products'] = 1) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_related_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('config_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_related_height'));
                }

                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }
```

On the product page appears the error: Notice: Undefined variable: result in /home/www/catalog/controller/product/product.php on line 430

line 430: $data['ask_question'] = $this->url->link('product/ask_question', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']);

Does anynone know what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$result` is not defined.

The only place where it is defined in your code is at line 335:

```
foreach ($results as $result)
```

Presumably, `$results` was empty, because

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

returned no result.